# How to pass long json object OR String to pop up window

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I am almost out of ideas now. I have two variables each carrying the string length of about 2000 Chars. i want to pass these variables to a pop up window. I am using very straight forward method i.e.

```
var OpenedWin3=window.open("sheetpreview.php?FormValues="+encodeURIComponent(formObject)+
 "&Expenses="+encodeURIComponent(expenses)");
```

Although all data is shown properly but after few seconds, In `Chrome`, window goes unresponsive. i doubt that i am exceeding the allowed `URL` length. But there is no `414` message. I'm using `Apache/2.2.11` server.

Is there some other way by which i can pass these two variables to new window like `POST` or `SESSION`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem once with a very long POST too which returned usually 403,404 error by server.

So I guess you should stick with `SESSION`.

Comment: but my whole code is in `.js` file and using `SESSION` would require further tweaking:(

Comment: Can you provide more information about this data?
I mean 2000 chars is a big data,what is contains?

Comment: You could also try and store it in cookie.

Comment: Cookies also has the Limit of `4K`.

Comment: Store the data temporary in database. Generate a code which can you use to open sheetpreview.php to render that template with the datas belong to it.